# How to store an external link in a word in a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, hyperlink, scripting

I would like to hyperlink a word with a url rather than printing the url itself while writing a shell script.
For example

```
curl -d "data=${LINK}" -X POST http://someurl
```

would send the data as so

```
https://message_link_address
```

I would like the message_link_address to be hyperlinked to the word "here"

For example, when we hit the curl command we should get the output as:

Click [here](https://message_link_address).

With here pointing to the original address. This curl command would be part of a shell script in linux.

Can this be done? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand what you have and what you need.  Please provide your efforts, show us your (non-working) code versions, these always make more clear what architecture you are having in mind.

Comment: what? bash is not a markup language!